# Getting undesired output when std::cout using arrow pointer

Tags: c++

I started to learn c++, and I'm trying to understand the arrow feature in c++. I have this example code, but I'm not getting the desired output.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
struct student {
    int age;
};

student* getStudent(int age ){
    student person;
    student *p;
    p = & person;
    p->age = age;
    return p;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    auto* d = getStudent(29);
    std::cout << d->age <<std::endl;
    std::cout << d->age <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```cpp
29
-2003661472
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Why am I getting this undesired output?

Comment: you return the address of a variable that is destroyed by the time you go to use the variable

Comment: You return a pointer to the `person` object that existed while `getStudent` was running. But then you try to dereference that pointer when `getStudent` is not running. No `student` object exists at that point since `person` went out of scope. So there is no person whose age you can print. A pointer to an object is only useful during that object's lifetime and may not be dereferences after the object it pointed to is gone.

Comment: If you compile your code with at least some basic and essential flags, you could save a lot of time. Compilers can catch this sort of thing easily in such cases. Please check out your compiler's manual page and get into a good compiling routine.